# A simple HTML table turning into a pain

Tags: html

What am I missing here?

```
<table border=2 width=80% bgcolor=#FFFFFF>
  <tr bgcolor=#C0C0C0>
    <th align=left>Specification</th>
    <th align=left>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align=left></td>
    <td align=left></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align=left>Test1</td>
    <td align=left>Test1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

what is causing the empty row under the title row?

Comment: Probably the two empty td's ;)

Comment: It has been a long day, too long... I looked at that for a long time and didn't see it. Thanks, I need to get back to php programming, scratch that... I need to get to bed. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<tr>
    <td align=left></td>
    <td align=left></td>
  </tr>
```

Will give you an empty row

Comment: Great answer for a `nice great` question, xD!

Answer (score 0):

run this code

```
    <table border=2 width=80% bgcolor=#FFFFFF>
    <tr bgcolor=#C0C0C0><th align=left>Specification</th><th align=left>Description</th></tr>
    <tr><td align=left>Test1</td><td align=left>Test1</td></tr>
    </table>
```